# Change text inside Span - DNN module

Tags: jquery

I have a module EasyNews DNN and I need change text inside Span, this is the original text:

```
<div class="edn_aditionalBox edn_articleLinks"> 

<h2><span>More links</span></h2>
<ul>
<li>
<a href="#" target="_blank">Text">
</li>
</ul>

</div>
```

I need change

```
<h2><span>More links</span></h2>
```

by

```
<h2><span>Download Document</span></h2>
```

Tanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
$('h2 span').text("Download Document");
```